# C# VSTO Excel - referencing Excel objects are inconsistent

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am writing an automation for an Excel workbook that contains some custom properties.
I expect the following:

```
    Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties MyProperties;
    MyProperties = Application.ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties;
    Office.DocumentProperty MyProperty2 = MyProperties.Item(CustomPropKey);
```

to be the same as:

```
    Office.DocumentProperty MyProperty = Application.ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Item(CustomPropKey);
```

However the first snippet fails with a red squiggly on the .Item(CustomProperty). The error is:

```
'DocumentProperties' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'DocumentProperties' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can anyone explain why snippet 2 does not work, but snippet 2 does work?

Comment: Should the c3.js tag be C#? If not, what's the relationship of c3.js to this question?

Comment: I *think* the problem is the fact that, in reality, the individual Office applications (Excel, Word, etc.) bring in the outside `Office` library using "late binding". Used to be, C# had to use PInvoke in order to access CustomDocumentProperties. When the "dynamic typing" was introduced, C# became able to work with CustomDocumentProperties in a similar manner to the VB languages. But I'm guessing it's still having some problems, such as what you're seeing.